# How to make @JoinTable a HashMap?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entities:

*User.java*:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;

 // this is relationship I want but being a map
 // @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//    @JoinTable(
//            name = "user_roles",
//            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
//            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
//    )

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "roleName")
    @Column(name = "roleValue")
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    )
    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<>();
}
```

*Role.java*:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Generated
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

No I am trying to have one table, `user_roles`, where the table would have (long user_id, long role_id, string userName, string userValue). Basically so that I can use it as a map (mapping for example `USER_ROLE` -> `USER_ROLE`, so that at frontend or anywhere the roles can be access via its name, not index). But I dont know how to do it. I know that `@JoinTable` and `@ElementCollection` both creates a table so how I can merged them (or simply just create one table that can be used in map)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this problem without complicated mapping, but just by writing the explicit transformation:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable( /* the mapping how it is */ )
private Set<Role> userRoles;

@Transient
public Map<String, String> getAttributes() {
    // convert userRoles to Map as you wish
}
```

Because as I understood, you want to collect information from `user`, `user_roles` and `role` tables, so your request will have two joins anyway.